# react-leaflet 1.x + create-react-app : 404 on marker image

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, create-react-app, react-leaflet

I tried using `react-leaflet` (in version 1.0.0-rc.2) with `create-react-app` but the marker image is in 404.

The generated image src is `http://{server_host}:3000/static/media/marker-icon.2273e3d8.png")marker-icon.png`

If I remove the weird `")marker-icon.png`, the image is good.

I got the same problem with the shadow image but was unable to guess the "real" image src.

You can reproduce the bug [here](https://react-leaflet-marker-bug.herokuapp.com/) and see the code [here](https://github.com/jdeniau/react-leaflet-marker-bug)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're hitting a variant of Leaflet bug [#4849](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4849). Upgrade to Leaflet 1.0.1, where it should be fixed.

Comment: Leaflet is already in 1.0.1 (see the [yarn.lock](https://github.com/jdeniau/react-leaflet-marker-bug/blob/master/yarn.lock#L3205) file)

Comment: You might want to submit a bug report to [react-leaflet](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet), then.

Comment: May be related to [this issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/5041). Added this as a "memo", I will try when the PR is merged